# How to orbit while translating (and otherwise navigate while using modal operators)?

Tags: 3d-view

I'm new to Blender and am soo excited to learn.

I've noticed that I can't do any navigating of the 3D view (orbiting, zooming, moving) while I'm in a modal operator. But, these are the times that I most want to change my view around, because I want to see from many perspectives what my operation is doing.

How can I navigate while in a modal operator? E.g., I want to orbit while in Translate (G) mode.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't. You *can* during modal operators (e.g. knife took (K)), but translate, rotate, etc. are not modal operators afaik.

Comment: @gandalf3 Thanks for replying. According to the following wki, Translate (or Grab, as it seems to be called) and Rotate are modal operators:  http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Interface#A_modal_operator